# jstack: Help on Java Thread Dump

Tags: java, thread-dump

I'm playing around with jstack. There is not much information about what the thread dump shows.

While playing around I got two different thread dumps:

Dump 1:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1115)
- locked <0x00000007e9a52840> (a org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
```

[...]

Dump 2:

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x9a000c30> (a org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1104)
- locked <0x9a000c30> (a org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
```

[...]

(For completeness: Both dumps are taken from a Tomcat 6 installation)

What to see here is:
- Both threads are in WAITING state.
- Both threads have entered a synchronized block in method borrowObject()
- Both threads seems to have called wait() on (different) objects of type GenericObjectPool$Latch.

What I also see is, that dump 2 shows "- waiting on ...", but dump 1 doesn't.
Why and what does it mean?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Best regards,
Markus